# How to allow vertical scroll on a container and horizontal overflow on the children at the same time?

Tags: css, google-chrome, android-webview, css-position

I have a scrollable div with many items which take >100% of viewport height.
This scrollable div must allow:

- vertical scrolling
- elements outside of the container (horizontal overflow)

Attempts and results:

1. When overflow = auto (`.el-list`), the container is scrollable but children (`.item`) are hidden when outside of the width of the container
2. When overflow = visible, not scrollable but overflow happens.

This does not semm to work because x and y are not treated independently (the idea is to **allow scroll y but still have x overflow**)

```
overflow-x: auto !important;
overflow-y: scroll !important;
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/1219368) explains why:

> If you are using visible for either overflow-x or overflow-y and something other than visible for the other, the visible value is interpreted as auto.

3. Setting `position: fixed` on the overflowing children allows it to overflow, but it ignores positioning to the parent entirely. and as expected `sticky` and `static` ignore also the `left:`  positioning.
4. same approach as 1-2 but with **.item rendered via :after/:before** doesn't change the result

**Code structure:** ([Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrt6g8za/38/))

```
.el-list {
 position: relative; 
 height: 100%
 width: 200px;
 overflow: auto; // treated as hidden
}

.item  { 
  position: relative;
}

.overlay-item {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}

   <div class="el-list">
     <div class="item"><div class="overlay-item"></div></div>
     <div class="item"><div class="overlay-item"></div></div>
   </div>
```

**Is there a way to achieve the expected behavior at least on webkit browsers (mobile webviews)?**

> ...ideally including the older android webview in android 4.*?

---

Edit: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) solution is interesting: no positioning except container's parent (bigger in width than parent ie `el-list` itself) seems **promising but not practical when there are several anscestors**

(there must be a reason why positioning ancestors is the foundation of dom element flow on the first place :-)! )

For refernce the HTML looks like this:

```
   <div class="el-list-parent"> <!-- parent of scrollable div -->
       <div class="el-list">
         <div class="item"><div class="overlay-item"></div></div>
         <div class="item"><div class="overlay-item"></div></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be 2 solutions to the problem I explained:

1. the [css-tricks approach](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) (set positioning relative to the window via javascript)

2. 

- making the parent (`.el-list`) without padding (in my case there was padding I could use to make the parent larger)
- compensate the missing parent's padding by applying it on its children (padding-left or padding-right where we want to have space but also horizontal overflow)